# How to render UICollectionviewcell's vertically with different cell sizes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I am trying to build a clone of Instagram, and I decided to use a UICollectionViewController that returns 3 different cells and I set the scroll direction to horizontal, and set the pagination to true, so that I can have three different pages in the 2 vertical cells I will be loading 2 other uicollectionviewcell's that are nested 1 for the feed 1 for the dm, I am running into an issue when it comes to hiding the navigation bar when the user gets to the camera because Instagram has the navigation bar displayed for the feed cell and the messaging cell but not for the camera one. Here below is my code for the maincollectionviewcontroller.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class MainViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let cellID = "cellId"
    let messageCellID = "messageCellID"
    let cameraCellID = "cameraCellID"
    var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let titleImage = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Instagram_logo"))
        titleImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.navigationItem.titleView = titleImage

        setupCollectionView()
        setupSwipeGesture()
       }

//    //Swipe right to get camera
//    func setupSwipeGesture() {
//        swipeRight.direction = .right
//        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
//        let cameraViewController = ViewController()
//        cameraViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
//        navigationController?.pushViewController(cameraViewController, animated: true)
//    }

    func setupSwipeGesture() {
        print("trying to swipe")
        swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swiped))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
        swipeRight.direction = .right
    }

    func swiped(){
        print("swipping to get Camera")
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        let cameraViewController = ViewController()
        cameraViewController.transitioningDelegate = self
        navigationController?.pushViewController(cameraViewController, animated: true)

    }


    func setupCollectionView(){

        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView?.register(MainViewFeedCellCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellID)
        collectionView?.register(MainViewMessagedFeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: messageCellID)
        collectionView?.register(MainViewCameraFeed.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cameraCellID)
        collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        scrollToMenuIndex(menuIndex: 0)
    }

    func goBackToMainPage(){
        scrollToMenuIndex(menuIndex: 0)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if (indexPath.item == 2){
            return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: messageCellID, for: indexPath)
        }

        else if (indexPath.item == 0){
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cameraCellID, for: indexPath)
            return cell
        }

        else if (indexPath.item == 1){
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath)
            return cell
        }

        else{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath)
            return cell
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        print("\(indexPath.row)")
//        if indexPath.row == 0{
//            navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
//            return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height:`      view.frame.height )
        //}
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - 70)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func scrollToMenuIndex(menuIndex: Int){
        let index = IndexPath(item: menuIndex, section: 0)
        collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: index, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve a similar problem was to add the UIScrollViewDelegate, to my UIViewController. Here's an interpretive answer based off of what you provided. Due to the fact that only one UICollectionViewCell appears at a time, this should do the trick. I'm not sure if this is the best way to get it done, but it worked for me:

```
var visibleCurrentCell: IndexPath? {
    for cell in self.collectionView.visibleCells {
        let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
        return indexPath
    }

    return nil
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(checkIfCameraIsShowing), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

func checkIfCameraIsShowing() {
    if let visibleCurrCell = visibleCurrentCell, let _ = collectionView.cellForItem(at: visibleCurrCell) as? CameraCollectionViewCell {
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }
}
```